# How to get all rows with only the max year within each category of a table in MYSQL (version 5.7)

Tags: mysql

I have a table of multiple rows with the categories and years:

| id | category | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | 2022 |
| 2 | cat1 | 2022 |
| 3 | cat1 | 2021 |
| 4 | cat2 | 2019 |
| 5 | cat2 | 2019 |
| 6 | cat2 | 2018 |
| 7 | cat2 | 2018 |

I am trying to create a query that only gets the rows with the latest year for each category resulting in:

| id | category | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | 2022 |
| 2 | cat1 | 2022 |
| 4 | cat2 | 2019 |
| 5 | cat2 | 2019 |

I have tried using GROUP BY but only get one row for each year and category:

```
SELECT 
 ANY_VALUE(`id`) AS `id`, 
 ANY_VALUE(`category`) AS `category`,
 MAX(`year`) AS `year` 
FROM `my_table` 
GROUP BY `category`,`year` 
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `category`
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `latest year for each category` why do `cat1` and `cat2` appear twice?

Comment: @user3783243, because `ID`s are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduce next:

```
SELECT 
 ANY_VALUE(`my_table`.`id`) AS `id`, 
 ANY_VALUE(`my_table`.`category`) AS `category`,
 ANY_VALUE(`my_table`.`year`) AS `year` 
FROM `my_table`, (SELECT ANY_VALUE(`category`) AS `category`, MAX(`year`) AS `year` FROM `my_table` GROUP BY `category`) AS `my_table2` 
WHERE 
    `my_table`.`year` = `my_table2`.`year` AND
    `my_table`.`category` = `my_table2`.`category`  
ORDER BY `my_table`.`year` DESC, `my_table`.`category`
```

Comment: Thanks! This gave me exactly what I needed and the query was very performant. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query with `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id), t1.category, t1.year 
FROM my_table t1 
INNER JOIN my_table t2 
ON t1.category = t2.category
WHERE t1.year > t2.year;
```

This query is more efficient as it doesn't involve any subqueries, aggregate functions or grouping.

Check [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pYYqNKB2ubQkMzNxkmvy3A/0)

Comment: It has one [issue](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pYYqNKB2ubQkMzNxkmvy3A/1).

Comment: My query is valid for given data. In given data all categories are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

here's a MySQL query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB T1
WHERE YEAR >= ALL (SELECT YEAR FROM TAB T2 WHERE T2.CATEGORY = T1.CATEGORY);
```